# Why does the PrepareStatement not generate correct SQL query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Below is my PrepareStatement code. It does not generate correct SQL-query.
Also it does not come beyond 1st println-statement. Also it says ** NOT SPECIFIED ** in the query (please see below).

How can we fix this, please?

```
   ps1 = con.prepareStatement(
                     "select stuId, name, relationsName, houseAddress, houseNumber from temp where "
                        + " stuId like '?%' and " 
                        + " sex = '?' and " 
                        + " name like '?%' and "
                        + " age BETWEEN ? and ? and "
                        + " relationsName like '?%' " 
                        + " order by name asc limit 0, 150000 "
               );

               System.out.println("ps1 Before : " + ps1);
```

output:

> ps1 Before : com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@14d55de: select
>   stuId, name, relationsName, houseAddress, houseNumber from temp where 
>   stuId like '?%' and  sex = '?' and  name like '?%' and  age BETWEEN **
>   NOT SPECIFIED ** and ** NOT SPECIFIED ** and  relationsName like '?%' 
>   order by name asc limit 0, 150000

It does not come beyond this point. Also it says **NOT SPECIFIED** in the query (please see to the end).

Any insights please?

```
       ps1.setString(1, stuId);
       ps1.setString(2, gender);
       ps1.setString(3, name);
       ps1.setInt(4, startAge);
       ps1.setInt(5, endAge);
       ps1.setString(6, relationsName);

       System.out.println("ps1 After : " + ps1);

       rs = ps1.executeQuery();
```

Comment: The `toString()` of a `PreparedStatement` is implementation defined and not something you should rely on in any way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

because the placeholders where enclosed with single quotes, thus making it a value an not a parameter anymore. you should get rid of it, eg

```
ps1 = con.prepareStatement(
                 "select stuId, name, relationsName, houseAddress, houseNumber from temp where "
                    + " stuId like ? and " 
                    + " sex = ? and " 
                    + " name like ? and "
                    + " age BETWEEN ? and ? and "
                    + " relationsName like ? " 
                    + " order by name asc limit 0, 150000 "
           );
```

for `LIKE` statement, you should concatenate the value in java, not in sql,

```
ps1.setString(1, stuId + '%');
```

Comment: Concatenation in the query itself should work as well (eg `? || '%'` or `? + '%'` or maybe even `{fn concat(?, '%')}`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, i agree with you. It's mysql so, use **concat**, `stuId like CONCAT(?, '%')`

Comment: The `{fn concat(..)}` is the JDBC escape for concatenation, it should make the query database-independent (as long as the driver supports the concat function escape).